# Getting errors after updating to the latest android sdk in eclipse

Tags: android, adt

I have 2 questions ,

I updated the android sdk and now the eclipse gives me this error at the startup. The error message is displayed below.

[image]

I clicked the check for updates button but there are no updates available now.

How to fix this problem?

second question is when a new project is created I can't choose sdk version for "Compile with" as it doesn't provide any choices.

[image]

as you can see on the above pic next and finish buttons are also disabled. So now I can't create a new project at all.

Is this because I updated the sdk version? (causes both problems)
I need help to fix both problems. 
Thanks.

Comment: try followin like in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16603961/2345913)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to the latest ADT Plugin. the current adt version is 22.0.1. [See here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) to know how to update ADT.

Answer (score 0):

Ive gotten that same error in the past - it tells me i need to update, yet no updates were available. Simply click the option underneath Check for updates, i believe it says Install New Software. Then choose the Android site from the list. Then you should be able to choose the available updates and install them. As for not being able to create a new project, im guessing thats either because you need to update, as you mentioned, OR, you need to download the sdk platform via the sdk manager. Hope this helps.